# Returning tr output to variable: Command Not Found

Tags: bash

```
N = hostname
echo $N //Output: ABC123
echo $N | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] //Output: abc123
N = $(echo $N | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]) //Output: Command not found
```

I can modify the hostname using tr and send it to the terminal, but I can't put it back into a variable. Why?

Comment: too much spaces : `N=$(...)` would likely work; isn't the exact error message `-bash: N : command not found` ? `N = something` is parsed as `launch the 'N' command with parameters '=' and 'something'`.

Comment: I also suggest to use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to lint your scripts, it would have caught this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two extra spaces surrounding the assignment operator (=).

```
N=$(echo $N | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])
```

The command above will work.

Comment: Thank you! I still have seven minutes until I can mark the correct answer, but thank you for quick reply.